# Offline satellite map of a specific area for an iOS app

Tags: mobile, satellite, ios, tilemill

I have a client that wants an offline satellite map as part of an iOS application. The map is of a specific area and needs to be able to be loaded without a connection. From my research I'm pretty sure I can do what I need to do using TileMill and route-me. There are two things that I don't understand:

1. Where can I get a satellite image that I can use in TileMill? (Paid is fine)
2. How do I get it into TileMill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy high resolution satellite images from [DigitalGlobe](http://www.digitalglobe.com/) or [GeoEye](http://www.geoeye.com/CorpSite/). You are not limited to these two map providers. There are too many options outside of these. You can also try Google Earth Pro for exporting images and with your license you can use Google Earth Pro images and data for marketing purposes as long as this data is not sold to any third parties.

For getting your raster into TileMill, there is a tutorial here: [Working with GeoTIFFs](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/)

I hope it helps you...

Comment: I downloaded one of the samples for GeoEye, but I can't seem to get it to work. Running gdalwarp says: ERROR 1: Too many points (26569 out of 26569) failed to transform,
unable to compute output bounds.

If I try to just add the tif as a layer in TileMill, nothing shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up reprojecting them in QGIS. It was a lot easier to visualize all of the different options.